# How do I cancel the refresh switch button after a page refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I would need advice on how to cancel the refresh position of the switch button when I switch to another chapter.

Code for js theme switch:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
if(localStorage.darkTheme === 'true'){
    document.body.classList.add('dark');
}
else{document.body.classList.remove('dark');};
const themeSwitch = document.getElementById('themeCheckBox');
themeSwitch.addEventListener('change', () => {    
    if (document.body.classList.contains('dark')){
        localStorage.darkTheme = 'false';
    }else { localStorage.darkTheme = 'true';};
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark');  
});
```

Comment: You can add the link for the website using markdown. `[litecode.net](http://litecode.net)`. Please follow a proper formatting when posting question. : D. And be specific when posting. What is the `js` code for your theme switch ?

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @NimnaPerera I've added a theme change code to my post

Comment: @wazz  I need to ask how to cancel the refresh on the switch button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript code should be changed like this. You have set the value of checkbox after `DOMContentLoaded` event triggered. And `add` or `remove` class according to the checkbox value.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const themeSwitch = document.getElementById('themeCheckBox');

    if(localStorage.darkTheme === 'true'){
        document.body.classList.add('dark');
        themeSwitch.checked = true;
    } else{
        document.body.classList.remove('dark');
        themeSwitch.checked = false;
    }

    themeSwitch.addEventListener('change', () => {    
        if (themeSwitch.checked){
            localStorage.darkTheme = 'true';
            document.body.classList.add('dark');
        } else {
            localStorage.darkTheme = 'false';
            document.body.classList.remove('dark');
        }  
    });
});
```